# How to call jquery click event using C#

Tags: c#, jquery

I have use the jquery click event for open popup like this.

```
$("#ctl00_login1").click(function () {
    $("#EmailPwd").addClass("Emailhide");
    $("#Email").removeClass("Emailhide");
    //centering with css
   centerPopup();
    //load popup
    loadPopup();
});
```

I want to call this click event using C# Code in asp.net to open popup like this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
call code here..
}
```

Comment: C# code that is located where?

Comment: Which framework? ASP.NET or MVC. it's difficult to diagnoise problem in currect form

Comment: The oversimplified answer is you can't. C# Code is executed on the server while javascript/jquery is executed client side in a web browser. Also what is the trigger for calling this event, what are your wanting to respond to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mahmoude Elghandour's answer is a good one but I would not actully fire the click event, but abstract out the code you want to fire. Then fire this code off in a document.ready event.

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function doPop(){
      $("#EmailPwd").addClass("Emailhide");
      $("#Email").removeClass("Emailhide");
      //centering with css
      centerPopup();
      //load popup
     loadPopup();
   }

   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#ctl00_login1").click(doPop());
   });
</script>
```

**C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "popIt", "$(document).ready(function(){doPop();});", true);
}
```

Comment: Thanx Jon for the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

try this

```
string jquery = "$("#target" ).click();"

 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "a key", 
         "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"+ jquery +"</script>"
                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is a client side framework. 
C# is probably your server's codes.

Now your server cannot call your client functions since then run on various client machines.

What you can do is render the page with c# conditions that will affect the client, something like this:

```
// the if is C# code
<%if(num == 1){%>
    alert( "Some code written here for..." );
<%}%>
```

if num is really 1, this will translate into this js code that will run:

```
alert( "Some code written here for..." );
```